# Changing and saving the data gives Integrity error

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, django-admin

I get Integrity with the below defined model.It occurs when I make changes and save the data again from the django admin.
The error is triggered by  obj.save() .
The error is as follows:

```
Exception Type: IntegrityError at /admin/users/data/1/change/
Exception Value: UNIQUE constraint failed: users_data.id
```

How can I make this right.

```
class Data(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, editable=False, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=300,blank=True,null=True,help_text=("enter the address"))
    contact = models.IntegerField(blank=True,null=True,help_text=("enter the contact"))
    username = models.CharField(max_length=100,blank=True,null=True,help_text=("enter the username"))
    password = models.CharField(max_length=100,blank=True,null=True,help_text=("enter the strong password"))
    creation_date = models.DateTimeField(editable=False,null=True)
    last_modified = models.DateTimeField(editable=False,null=True)

    def save(self,*args, **kwargs):
        if not self.creation_date:
            self.creation_date = timezone.now()
        self.last_modified = timezone.now()

        return super(Data, self).save(self,*args, **kwargs)

    def __str__(self):
        return (self.username)


@receiver(post_save,sender=Data)
def datasaver(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    address = instance.address
    contact = instance.contact
    username = instance.username
    user_password = instance.password

class CustomAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    search_fields = ('first_name', 'email', 'username', )

    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
        obj.author = request.user
        obj.password = ''
        obj.save()

    def get_queryset(self, request):
        qs = super(CustomAdmin, self).get_queryset(request)
        if request.user.is_superuser:
            return qs
        return qs.filter(author=request.user)
```

Comment: Your post_save signal handler seems to be completely pointless. Why do you have it?

Comment: But you're going to need to show the full traceback if you want us to help.

Comment: Don't do that. use this `creation_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)` and `last_modified = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)` and remove your save method

Comment: It did solve the problem. Thanks for the help. I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't do this. Django provides a better way to save the modified date and creation date. Use this instead and remove the overridden save method and post save signal.

Replace

```
creation_date = models.DateTimeField(editable=False,null=True)
last_modified = models.DateTimeField(editable=False,null=True)
```

with

```
creation_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
last_modified = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

See [django datefield optional arguments](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/fields/#datefield)

Comment: Thanks for the help.It worked.I really appreciate your help :)

Comment: @VishnuChalil please mark it as the answer if it helped

Comment: Note that auto_now should be on last_modified field and auto_now_add on creation_date field otherwise creation date field will keep getting changed